# Broadcast Intent receive null value

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

The code here will do the update of textview and the listview using background service.

Broadcastservice class

```
public class BroadcastService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastService";
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.activity.displayevent";
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Intent intentBS;
    int counter = 0;
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        intentBS = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);    
}
 @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intentBS, int startId) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second

    }

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getShiftCode();         
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000); // 10 seconds
        }
    };    
private void getShiftCode() {
     List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
     headers.add(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"));

     EmployeeRestClient.get(BroadcastService.this, "RestExample/shiftcode", 
    headers.toArray(new Header[headers.size()]),null, 
        new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
     ArrayList<String> scArray = new ArrayList<String>();

       for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
        try {
             String Sc_array = c.getString("shift_Code");
             scArray.add(Sc_array);
             } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
                shift_Code1= scArray.get(0);
                intentBS.putExtra("shift_Code1", shift_Code1);

           getEmployees();
           sendBroadcast(intentBS);

         }
    });
 }

private void getEmployees() {
     List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
     headers.add(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"));

     EmployeeRestClient.get(BroadcastService.this, "RestExample/employee", 
    headers.toArray(new Header[headers.size()]),null, 
        new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
     ArrayList<String> employeeArray1 = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> employeeArray2 = new ArrayList<String>();

       for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
        try {
              String  First_NameArray = c.getString("first_Name");
          String  Second_NameArray = c.getString("second_name");
          employeeArray1.add(First_NameArray );
          employeeArray2.add(Second_NameArray );

             } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
             intentBS.putExtra("employee_Array1", employeeArray1);
         intentBS.putExtra("employee_Array2", employeeArray2);
      }
    });
 }
```

Error Detail:

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.example.activity.displayevent flg=0x10 (has extras) } and
> ```
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

The nullpointerexception points to my `first_Name.getCount()` method in my adapterclass 
and these lines of my activity

```
updateUI(intentBS);
private void updateUI(Intent intentBS) {
final  MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter (SecondActivity.this,nameArray1,nameArray2);
```

But the broadcast sent is not able to receive in the activity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, maybe I missed something, but if I understood the code correctly your problem is that you not sending both array lists.

In `shiftCode` method you calling api method `"RestExample/shiftcode"` and register custom listener to it. Then on `onSuccess` callback you have these two lines:

```
getEmployees();
sendBroadcast(intentBS);
```

According to your idea first method should prepare `intentBS` and second send this intent with employees. But it will not happend. Because firstly `sendBroadcast(intentBS)` will invoked and then you will fill `intentBS` with employee data, because `getEmployees` using Api call, which goes to another thread and then lately (after `sendBroadcast`) invoke `onSuccess` callback.

So in fact at first you send broadcast and only then fill `intentBS`

Comment: I some what understood what you are saying. Actually i am getting shiftcode value if i disable getemployees() method.So what should i do now to get the arraylist values.

Comment: @user3785322 In your case as fast solution you can easily move `sendBroadcast(intentBS);` to `getEmployees` and put it after `intentBS.putExtra("employee_Array2", employeeArray2);`

Comment: Great. It worked. I tried everything else, except this. By the way is it right way to do this.

Comment: @user3785322 Glad to help you. Sorry, I don't know full code base of you project and don't know for example why you have handler with 10s delay. But in abstract general case, I would prefer to support synchronous rest calls and made for example IntentService inheritor. Thus code would be more elegant and straightforward.

Comment: @user3785322 will appreciate if you mark the answer as correct

Comment: Okay i will try with IntentService. Thanks for the suggestion.Of course i am gonna do it. Actually did it.